# Express + React: auto-filled input doesn't pass the value to the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express

I run into an issue coding my "insert item" component. I need to save the current user ID for sorting in the future every item uploaded from different users. Now I tried to pass it using the setState method but it doesn't return the value and it doesn't pass to the onSubmit method. So I decided to make an auto filled input in my form that gets the user ID and makes it available in the form by setting the value={user._id} but it works just one time. Now MongoDB gives me a `Path 'user_id' is required`  every time I submit a new item. Does anyone know how to fix this issue??

My component :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { addRoom } from '../actions/itemActions';

import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, FormText } from 'reactstrap';

class AddRoom extends Component {
    state = {
        name: '',
        where: '',
        ospiti: 1,
        descr: '',
        fumo: false,
        animali: false,
        prezzo: 1,
        user_id: '',
    };

    static propTypes = {
        auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    onChange = e => {
        this.setState({ 
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
            [e.target.user_id]: e.target.value,
        });
    };

    onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const newRoom = {
            name: this.state.name,
            where: this.state.where,
            descr: this.state.descr,
            ospiti: this.state.ospiti,
            prezzo: this.state.prezzo,
            fumo: this.state.fumo,
            animali: this.state.animali,
            user_id: this.state.user_id
        }

        this.props.addRoom(newRoom);
    }

    render() {
        const { user } = this.props.auth;

        return (
            <div className="addroom-cont">
                <h3>Carica una struttura:</h3>
                <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="name">Titolo</Label>
                        <Input type="text" name="name" id="titolo-struttura" placeholder="Aggiungi un titolo" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="where">Città</Label>
                        <Input type="text" name="where" id="lugo" placeholder="Aggiungi un luogo" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="prezzo">Prezzo per notte</Label>
                        <Input type="number" name="prezzo" id="prezzo" placeholder="$" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="ospiti">Numero Ospiti</Label>
                        <Input type="select" name="ospiti" id="Numero Ospiti" onChange={this.onChange}>
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                            <option>6</option>
                            <option>7</option>
                            <option>8</option>
                            <option>9</option>
                        </Input>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="descr">Aggiungi Una Descrizione</Label>
                        <Input type="textarea" name="descr" id="descr" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label check inline>
                        <Input type="checkbox" name="fumo" id="fumo" onChange={this.onChange}/>{' '}
                            Fumatori
                        </Label>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label check inline>
                        <Input type="checkbox" name="animali" id="animali" onChange={this.onChange}/>{' '}
                            Ammessi Animali
                        </Label>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="file">Aggiungi Una Foto</Label>
                        <Input type="file" name="room-photo" id="room-photo" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                        <FormText color="muted">
                        Aggiungi delle foto che mostrano la struttura in che desideri caricare sulla nostra piattaforma.
                        </FormText>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="user_id">ID Utente</Label>
                        <Input value={user._id} type="text" name="user_id" id="user_id" onChange={this.onChange} />
                    </FormGroup>

                    <Button>Carica Struttura</Button>
                </Form>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    room: state.room,
    auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addRoom })(AddRoom);
```

Comment: Did you try user_id: this.props.auth.user._id when you fill the newRoom variable, because this.state.user_id is undefined

Comment: at one place you are using ```user._id``` , I think you need ```user_id``` (extra . is there where label is "ID Utente")

Comment: I put `this.props.auth.user._id` in my component and now it works! thank you so much, I was confused by the variables themselves!!